# Make number size match in page header

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fontsize, small-caps

I want to achieve page headers that are lowercase small capitals. MWE below:

```tex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\scshape}
\ohead{\MakeLowercase{\headmark}}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\end{document}
```

---

However, the numbers are a little too big:

[image]

---

What I have tried so far is to use below code instead

```tex
\ohead{\footnotesize\MakeUppercase{\headmark}}
```

which leads to this result:

[image]

It is close, but to me, the scaled uppercase small capitals look a little different compared to "real" lowercase small capitals.

---

- Is there any way to have lowercase small capitals with appropriately-sized chapter / section numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine `\chaptermarkformat` and `\sectionmarkformat` to get smaller chapter and section numbers in header:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[automark,markcase=lower]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{{\footnotesize\thechapter\autodot}\enskip}
\renewcommand*\sectionmarkformat{{\footnotesize\thesection\autodot}\enskip}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\scshape}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\Blindtext
\section{A section}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```